# How to insert a formula inside an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, reference, formula

I found this amazing formula:

`=SUM(INDEX(data,N(IF(1,{1,3,5}))))` by Jeff Weir.

But I need to reference the numbers inside an array with some formula. Here is an example:

```
=SUM(INDEX(data,N(IF(1,{Rows(A4:A7),3,5}))))
```

Excel does not want to execute this. What can I do?

*My problem is more complicated in reality, but this info will help me a lot (I think).*

//EDIT

My goal is for Excel to return me the "Price" of a certain "Name" (let's say Oil), within a certain "Date" range (let's say within March 2020). Also, it has to be the latest date in this range. So, in this case, I want Excel to return me the price "80" (the price of Oil), as 20.3.2020 is later than 2.3.2020. Imagine I have a lot of data, with a lot of names, dates, and prices.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You should state what you want to accomplish. What you tried and how that works and why it does/n't work. Also usually a spreadsheet or at least a screenshot of it helps a lot

Comment: @SJR I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Use CHOOSE to return the array:

```
=SUM(INDEX(data,N(IF(1,CHOOSE({1,2,3},ROWS(A4:A7),3,5)))))
```

Depending on one's version this formula may require the use do Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]